# Updating wordpress custom field after extracting youtube thumbnail

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a shortcode to display video from custom field "tube_video_url".
Now what I wish to do is to automaticly add mqdefault image to custom filed "fifu_image_url" of the same video.

I made this shortcode for myself...

```
function video( $atts, $content = "" ) {
$string     = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tube_video_url', TRUE);
$search     = '/youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/smi';
$replace    = 'youtube.com/embed/$1';    
$content = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
    return '<iframe id="video-frame" width="560" height="315" src="'.$content.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
}
add_shortcode( 'video', 'video' );
```

Now I am not sure how to turn this...
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yJS-byLHrU
into this...
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/2yJS-byLHrU/mqdefault.jpg

I tried something like

```
$string     = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yJS-byLHrU';
$search     = '/youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/smi';
$replace    = 'i.ytimg.com/vi/$1/mqdefault.jpg';  
$content = preg_replace($search, $replace, $string);
    echo $content;
```

Result comes to `https://www.i.ytimg.com/vi/2yJS/mqdefault.jpg-byLHrU`, note how `-byLHrU`is put after jpg, and also how do I fill the custom field "fifu_image_url' with this value of image once submit button is pressed or at first post visit?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract youtube video id using url as following

```php
$link = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2yJS-byLHrU";
$video_id = explode("?v=", $link);

if (empty($video_id[1]))
    $video_id = explode("/v/", $link);
$video_id = explode("&", $video_id[1]); 
$video_id = $video_id[0]; // will print the output -> 2yJS-byLHrU
```

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is, what when $link is not an youtube url?

Comment: @Esteros as you explain this function extracts the youtube id from youtube URL. since you have the youtube id you can use it for generating the thumbnail. if given URL is not a youtube one you can return custom default thumbnail for that.

Answer (score 0):

Found answer, I will post it if anyone needs in future...

```
/* Do something with the data entered */
add_action( 'save_post', 'myplugin_save_postdata' );

/* When the post is saved, saves our custom data */
function myplugin_save_postdata( $post_id ) {

  // First we need to check if the current user is authorised to do this action. 
  if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
        return;
  } else {
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) )
        return;
  }


$url = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'tube_video_url', TRUE);
preg_match('%(?:youtube(?:-nocookie)?\.com/(?:[^/]+/.+/|(?:v|e(?:mbed)?)/|.*[?&]v=)|youtu\.be/)([^"&?/ ]{11})%i', $url, $match);
$youtube_id = $match[1];

  $mydata = 'https://i.ytimg.com/vi/'. $youtube_id. '/mqdefault.jpg'; // Do something with $mydata 


  update_post_meta( $post_id, 'fifu_image_url', $mydata );
}
```

Unfortunatelly this works only posting from back-end.